# Mex compiled code fails to run while gcc works

Tags: matlab, gcc, mex

I have been trying to get a mex wrapper on some cpp code that uses Boost libraries to work. But it doesn't.

Both mex and g++ compile the code fine, but a call to the mexfunction fails with an error:

```
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.
What() is:std::bad_alloc
```

from within the boost serialization library (as I figured from GDB) it loads while that of CPP works fine. They run on exactly the same input and load the same libraries at run-time.
As I understand mex uses gcc (set through the `mex -setup`) should behave just like GCC compiled code. I am not sure where to look for the problem.

1. MEX throws a warning that it supports GCC 4.3.4 and not GCC 4.6.4 that is installed. I am not expecting this to be the problem. Boost libraries are version 1.51
2. The core function takes the filename and reads the input from the file. Instantiates a class, does some operations and dumps the instance to a tmp file through boost serialization library. 
   And then depending on the subsequent call, reads the instance back through serialization, performs operations and dumps it back to the temp file.
   It is while trying to read the instance back from the file that the mex compiled code leaves an error while GCC compiled code works. An outline is as follows:

   ```
   class T { 
       Tree( std::string input ); //reads input and builds 
       void dump( std::string tmp ); //dumps D to tmp
       void read( std::string tmp); //reads tmp and builds D
       void operation1( std::string tmp); //reads D from tmp,does op1,dumps back D
       void operation2( std::string tmp); //reads D from tmp,does op2,dumps back D

       DataStructure D;
   };
   ```

Is there a way I could figure out why this could be happening or am I missing something obvious. Any suggestions could be helpful. I could add more details as necessary.